# OCLint generates empty compile_commands.json

Tags: xcode, xcode5, static-analysis, lint

I have successfully installed oclint in my mac and trying to run it,
I am following steps described [Here](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/guide/xcode.html) but while running the OCLint target it shows some error inside the UIKit and CoreFoundation frameworks.

Also showing error

```
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Then I tried like [this](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/guide/xcodebuild.html) its generating xcodebuild.log correctly(I think), but when I executing oclint-xcodebuild its creating compile_commands.json file that contains only an empty array.

Using

OCLint 0.9 dev build for darwin/x86_64

Xcode Version 5.0 (5A1413)

OS X 10.8.5

**UPDATE:**

Finally after clean and build compile_commands.json generates correctly, but getting so many errors inside the framework. How can I build this without generating error in framework?

Also how can I avoid

```
long line P3 Line with 108 characters exceeds limit of 100
```

this warning while using OCLint?

Comment: Can you show the script that's being run?

Comment: @trojanfoe https://gist.github.com/lqi/5358513 directly copied from here

Comment: Well I don't see that script doing any kind of error checking or statements like `exit 1` so I would conclude that it's a crap script to use.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need to add this -rc=LONG_LINE=300. you can see more examples [here](http://kalkanotel.com/xcodebuild-generating-empty-compilecommandsjson-i207654.htm)

check this: oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o report.html -rc=LONG_LINE=120" open compile_commands.json open report.html